# Metodo Entry tkinter: limitar caracteres

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7, interfaz-gráfica, interface

Tengo este codigo. Parte de un juego del ahorcado, que estoy armando. tengo un Entry de ttkinter donde se ingresa la palabra. Necesito limitar la cantidad de letras a ingresar. Intente varias formas de limitarlo, incluso una que aparece en una de las preguntas pero no lo pude solucionar

```
class ContenedorIngresaPalabra:
    def __init__(self, framePrincipal:PantallaTitulo = None):
         self.frameIngresarPalabra = framePrincipal
         self.contenedor= tk.Frame(self.frameIngresarPalabra)
         self.contenedor.config(background="grey")    
         self.contenedor.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.40, relheight=0.30)
         self.ingresoPalabra()
         self.botonesIngresoPalabra()
    
    def ingresoPalabra(self):
         self.titulo = tk.Label(self.contenedor, text="INGRESE PALABRA:")
         self.titulo.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.10, relwidth=0.60, relheight=0.20)
         self.titulo.config(bg="red", fg="black", font=("Showcard Gothic", 15))
    
         self.dato = tk.StringVar()
         self.ingreso = ttk.Entry(self.contenedor,textvariable=self.dato, width=1)
         self.ingreso.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.50, relheight=0.15)
         self.dato.trace_add('write', lambda *args: self.dato.set(self.dato.get().upper())) 
                      
    
    def botonesIngresoPalabra(self):
         self.volver = BotonFila(self.contenedor, "VOLVER", 4, 0.2,1, 0.05, 0.2)
         self.volver.boton["command"] = self.comandoVolver
    
         self.comenzar = BotonFila(self.contenedor, "COMENZAR", 4, 0.2,2, 0.05,0.2)
         self.comenzar.boton["command"] = self.comandoComenzar
    
    def comandoVolver(self):
         self.frameIngresarPalabra.laVentana.menuPrincipal = PantallaModoJuego(unaVentana = self.frameIngresarPalabra.laVentana)
         self.frameIngresarPalabra.destroy()

    def comandoComenzar(self):
        palabra = self.dato.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

la forma como se limita el numero de caracteres en un entry es con el parametro width, el cual estas usando = 1, luego debe mostrarte 1 solo caracter.
despues lo puedes cambiar con configure, pero debes tener presente que si el tamaño del entry cambia la posicion de los otros widget se altera de acuerdo al tipo de empaquetado (grid pack o place) que hayas usado para empaquetar el entry.

Con el siguiente ejemplo: entre un Label y un Botón un Entry con un ancho 2 puede ser definido con una variable inicial ancho y luego en la definicion del entry usarlo como variable e1 guarda el tamaño de caracteres de ese entry, pero al cambiar el numero y oprimir el boton puedes cambiar el tamaño del entry y el botón a su derecha se movera de acuerdo al pack usado para empaquetar los widgets.

´´´´    import tkinter as tk

```
w = tk.Tk()
w.geometry("400x300+0+0") 
w.config(bg="#AAA") 
ancho=2
l0=tk.Label(w,text="Ancho de este entry")
l0.pack(side="left")
e1=tk.Entry(w,width=2,textvariable=ancho)
e1.pack(side="left")
b0=tk.Button(w,text="cambiar ancho",command=lambda:         
e1.configure(width=e1.get()))
b0.pack(side="left") 

w.mainloop()
```

GRacias a Dante S que me explico mejor la pregunta El entry trae un parametro validate que define de que forma se va a validar la informacion den Entry, si pones Key se validara cada vez que se oprima el teclado, hay otras opciones como focus con el mouse.

El entry por defecto tiene un metodo de validacion, que puede llamar a una funcion definida antes del entry.

Como ventaja esa funcion puede ser definida con mas aspectos como que teclas si funcionan o cuales no.

Lo importante es que esa funcion debe devolver un True si se quiere que el Entry acepte la ultima tecla.
o deberá devolver False si quiere que el Entry descarte la tecla oprimida.

para acceder a dicha funcion se puede con el parametro validatecommand o vcmd llamando a la funcion que valida y que debe devolver el booleano. tambien puede hacerse con un lambda, pero como desventaja es que los lambdas tendrian que contener condicionales para otras teclas como backspace o delete, que por espacio caben bien en la funcion normal y un lambda se vuelve muy confuso, lo cual va en contra de las buenas practicas de python.

Si hay validatecommand, implica que el Entry necesita una forma para validar el texto dentro del campo de texto.

en un evento se hace con el disparador del evento como   o  con el parametro validate=key cada vez que se oprime una tecla, el entry ejecuta el validatecommand de igual forma que el entry.

Si se usa validatecommand, el Entry espera un Booleano True o false para saber si acepta o no la ultima tecla.

En caso que no se use validatecommand sino que se haga un evento sobre el widget con bind, habra que hacer que la cadena del Entry descarte la ultima tecla, puede ser borrando parte de la cadena asi:

Si lo que devuelve el validatecommand es True, el Entry acepta la tecla que se oprima, si devuelve false, no acepta la tecla y no sigue llenando el campo.

con unlambda que revisa solo la longitud del campo < 10, mientras el campo tenga menos de 10 caracteres escritos aceptaria otra tecla como el Backspace, de lo contrario, al llegar a los 10 caracteres, el resultado del lambda es false, y la tecla como un bacspace no se acepta, y no se podria modificar el texto tampoco con delete por ejemplo.

Los lambda son muy minimos y no permiten una mejor explicacion de la funcion de validacion.

La funcion de validacion podria definirse antes de definir

En TCL se supera facil, porque las funciones se pueden definir en la misma linea que crea el entry, por ejemplo:

```
place [entry .w.e -validate key -invcmd bell -vcmd {expr {[string length %P]<10}}] -x 0 -y 50
```

la opcion -validate le indica al widget como quiere que se haga la validacion, puede ser al teclear key, o al hace focus con el mouse.
la opcion -invcmd bell en tkinter no funciona, en Tkinter, pero en TCL si suena la campana del sistema de error, avisando que se cumple la sentencia de la validacion.
pero usando el evento bind se podria poner que el fondo del entry cambie de color, por ejemplo de #FFF blanco a #000 negro
En Tkinter los lambda son caoticos, definitivamente TCL es mejor para este tipo de scripts en la misma linea.

lo mejor es hacer una funcion anterior, que se evalue con -validate  Key

Cuando se me presentan dudas de tkinter yo recurro a la documentacion de TCL, [documentacion de TCL](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TkCmd/entry.htm) es mas confiable y explica mejor, y luego busco eso mismo en python [Muy buen tutor no solo de python, sino de Ruby y Perl, pues Tkinter al ser TCL es casi el mismo codigo](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#entry)

Ejemplo de un entry que limita a 3 caracteres:

```
import tkinter as tk
w=tk.Tk()
w.geometry("600x250+0+0")
def limitar():
print(a+str(len(a)))
cadena=e0.get()
if len(cadena)>4:
    return False
else:
    return True 
e0 = tk.Entry(w, validate="key",validatecommand=(lambda: len(e0.get()) < 3))
e0.place(x=100, y=100)
w.mainloop()
```

Le agradezco a todos porque me dieron la oportunidad de investigar y poder aprender mas de este tema, llevo unos 10 años programando en TCL, y nunca me habia tomado el tiempo de aprenderlo en profundidad.

Comment: width no limita el numero de caracteres, si no que determina el tamaño del entry en base a asumir que todos los caracteres miden lo mismo.